# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'. using fill array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
interface Itype { 
    type: number;
    name?: string;
}    

function makeEqualArrays(arr1: Itype[], arr2: Itype[]): void { 
      arr2 = arr2.concat([].fill({ type: 2 }, len1 - len2));
}
```

Why I can not fill array by object?

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Comment: `fill`ing an empty array will always give you an empty array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: Not always, it also returns empty array: `let a: any[] = [{type: 1}];

a.fill({ type: 1 }, 0, 4);
console.log(a);
`

Comment: `a` is not empty in your above example.

Comment: No it is filled by one value `let a: any[] = [{type: 1}];`

Comment: Thus, my first comment still holds. `fill`ing an empty array with `Array.prototype.fill` has no effect. There are no array elements to mutate.

Comment: How then to fill array? if i have filled array with element 3 and I need to add also 3 elements?

Comment: This also does not work: ` arr2 = arr2.concat(new Array(len1 - len2).fill({ type: 2 }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to type the new array you are creating `[]` like :

```
([] as Itype[])
```

---

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJJgJ4AcUG9kBQyxymOAXMiAK4C2ARtANxEkhy0QD8lAzmFFABzFgF8ShAjGogEYYAHsQyWnADWEAKIBHanAA2AQShQ4GXgAo4JgIyV02CAG0AugBpk1qACZ7ZZy4AlJQAbgrAACbI+KzEXt7IALyeJt4AdAhKCHBgFhaunrxo-q6BaTDA+voWuLESpI6U3m7snHWiHgCsgYFiQA)

```
interface Itype { 
    type: number;
    name?: string;
}    

function makeEqualArrays(arr1: Itype[], arr2: Itype[]): void { 
    arr2 = arr2.concat(([] as Itype[]).fill({
        type: 2,name
    }, 5));
}
```

Comment: Why I get empty array instead filled: `console.log(([] as Itype[]).fill({ type: 1 }, 0))`?

Comment: So actually Array.fill doesnt work the way you think. `
console.log((new Array(10) as Itype[]).fill({ type: 1 }));` it only fill an existing array, it doesnt push new values in it. Look at the code in my comment